# I can't write in a book and quill

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I tried to write in a book and quill I wrote it then press "done" but then the game crashed, with the error

> You tried to flood with CUSTOM_PAYLOAD packet

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Comment: Are you or the server using any mods?

Comment: Im not and i dont think the server is

Comment: Did this only happen once, or multiple times?

Comment: Well it keeps happening when i try to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug it seems. I found a forum that is discussing the same bug, although I did not find more about the bug.

http://www.mccentral.org/forum/m/17339729/viewthread/30097331-creative-book-quil-bug

I guess it will get solved eventually, if your server people are not aware of it, do contact them about it.